# Convert cURL request to request of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, request, httprequest

Here is my valid cURL command:

```
curl 'https://www.example.com/api/' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getObjectsByFilter","id":"3"}'
```

here is what I tried in Node.js:

```
var url = 'https://www.example.com/api/';

var data = {
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id":"3"
};

req.post({ url: url, form: data}, function (err, result, body) {
```

But it is not valid.

Comment: This site automatically generates a node request from a cURL request. https://curl.trillworks.com/

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following tool to convert and get the code:

https://curl.trillworks.com/#node

They support:

- Node.js
- Python
- PHP

Comment: Bless you for this.

Answer (score 13):

You can also do it using postman if you have. (late answer but might help someone else)
1. import curl command into the postman
[image]

2. After import click on the code and you can see many options to generate the code for different languages. 
   [image]

Answer (score 5):

You are going to need to install the npm module [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

If you have `npm` installed already, just run the following command:

```
npm install request
```

Make sure you require the module at the top of your node file, like so

```
var request = require('request');
```

You can use the module with the following:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://www.example.com/api/';

var data = {
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id":"3"
};

request.post({url:url, formData: data}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('post failed:', err);
  }

  console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

Check the documentation out for more information:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: I get an error: "Object #<Object> has no method 'on'"

Comment: @llshat you must be doing something wrong, because I didn't write any code that uses `on`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programatically generate nodejs code from curl then try [httpsnippet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpsnippet) by Kong.

[httpsnippet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpsnippet) support lots of languages and is being actively maintained by Kong.

> HTTP Request snippet generator for many languages & tools including: cURL, HTTPie, Javascript, Node, C, Java, PHP, Objective-C, Swift, Python, Ruby, C#, Go, OCaml and more!